# AlarmManager not started at specified timing

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I was having some problem when trying to start the alarm manager in Android to send push-notifications upon certain condition.

So basically what I am trying to do is I have a list of events, the system will send a push notification on events' eve. And here is the part where I grab the event date and make comparison:

```
for (int count = 0; count < _eventlist.size(); count++) {

        Date alarmDate = null;
        try {
            alarmDate = dateFormat.parse(_eventlist.get(count)
                    .getEventDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(alarmDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        Date alarmBeforeOneDay = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        if (dateFormat.format(alarmBeforeOneDay).equals(currentDate)) {
            if (!AlarmInitialized(context)) {
                notifyEventName = _eventlist.get(count).getEventName();
                notifyEventTime = _eventlist.get(count).getEventTime();
                notifyEventAddress = _eventlist.get(count).getEventAddress();
                notifyEventPic = _eventlist.get(count).getEventPic();
                scheduleAlarms(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

If today is the event's eve, I will then execute the scheduleAlarm() to start the broadcast receiver:

```
public static void scheduleAlarms(Context context) {
    int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
    int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm");
    String time = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + "00" + "-" + "30";

    Date dt = null;
    try {
        dt = df.parse(time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long when = dt.getTime();

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

    notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventName", notifyEventName);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventTime", notifyEventTime);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventAddr", notifyEventAddress);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventPic", notifyEventPic);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
}
```

So basically the push notification part was working perfectly. I did received it. However, the push notification only shows up when I launch the Activity.

**It does not send according to the timing I have set in the method previously.** In this case, it was supposed to send a push notification at 12:30 AM if today is the event's eve. However, from my code, when it reaches 12:30 AM and it does not send. It will only send when I run the Activity itself.

Any guides/ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send notification from this activity or any service? I mean what the context of executing scheduleAlarms(Context context) ?

Comment: It's activity. Then from the scheduleAlarm() I will execute the onReceive which extends to BroadcastReceiver

Comment: If you need to notificate user when app is "closed", you need to use service, cause when you roll up activity, method onStop is calling within activity lifecycle, and in this activity can be destroyed. Service will still working and notificate user. Aren't you tried service?

Comment: I thought AlarmManager itself was a service? Would you mind to provide me some solutions which I could implement them?

Comment: there is a good example - http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did. But somehow the alarm manager is not triggered by the time I set it. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Because from what I see from the link you suggested, I am doing the same way

Comment: now no idea... maybe will try to do this, when i will get some free time

Comment: i did not found a time to try it yet =_=, but can you try to use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html ?